# Do melee and ranged spell attack rolls have advantage against a stunned creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, conditions, advantage-and-disadvantage

In D&D 5e, if a creature has a condition such as [*Stunned*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Stunned), then:

> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.

Does this benefit also apply to spells that require melee or ranged spell attack rolls to hit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If you make an attack roll, you are making an attack.

Ironically, the Rick and Morty D&D source has what I think is the clearest statement to help us out here:

> Whenever you make an attack roll, you’re making an attack. Whether you’re striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has the following structure...

That should clear it up. Melee and ranged spell attacks require attack rolls, so would have advantage against a stunned creature.

The PHB reads similarly in the section [Making an Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack):

> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure. [...]
>
> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.

*Stunned* gives an attacking creature advantage on all attack rolls, and melee and ranged spell attacks make attack rolls and would be made at advantage.